# Why are broomsticks associated with Witches?

Tags: witches, folklore

It's a given. Witches ride flying broomsticks. Why? How did brooms become a part of their bag of tricks?

Comment: ...because witch stories derive from "hags" which derived from elderly women, who were known to have a broom hanging around for sweeping.

Comment: Because vacuum cleaners hadn't been invented yet.

Comment: @GorchestopherH I hate Karma.

Answer (score 3):

See this URL: http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/1344/whats-the-deal-with-witches-and-broomsticks

> You don't want to hear it, mom. Well, maybe you do, but you don't want to tell the kids. As we've learned from our previous forays into folklore, most of these old rituals have something to do with S-E-X. You thought Easter eggs and bunnies as fertility symbols was kinky? You ain't heard nothin' yet.

I won't quote the actual article, as it's a bit too racy (PG-13 version: you used the broom as a giant Q-tip to administer flying ointmemt), but its main source of info seems to be Michael J. Harner's "The Role of Hallucinogenic Plants in European Witchcraft" in Hallucinogens and Shamanism (1973).

This is also somewhat confirmed (probably from same sources) on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Besom_broom)

Comment: Magrat was about to tell Granny that, then decided not to.

Comment: This would deserve an upvote if you put the actual gist in your answer. Use a spoiler tag in conjunction with a big disclaimer if you think it's unsuited for minors or offensive in some way.

Comment: @bitmask - I'd rather NOT get yelled at by mods. Feel free to ask them in meta if it's OK, if they say so, I will let you edit it in (or do myself)

Comment: Come on, this is ridiculous. Do we really have to decide on meta that it is okay to actually answer questions?

Comment: Gives that [Geico commercial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3btVEGC00Ns) a whole new meaning.

Comment: @bitmask - we don't **have to**. I personally just don't want to without explicit OK.

Comment: Fun fact: Witches actually were said to ride their broomsticks backwards from what we would think (the bristles of the broom in the front whilst the stick pointed to the back).